# will redis be a good fit for huge volume of data?

Tags: redis

I want to use redis as a data store in a project.
But I am not clear how much data(size) can redis handle.

I am looking at 4-5 terabyte of data.

Please let me know if redis will a suitable option.

I am well aware of all the advantages/features of redis. just not sure about the scalability options.

Any information on this is much appreciated.

Comment: `I am well aware of all the advantages/features of redis` - really? [I can't have a dataset larger the memory](http://redis.io/topics/faq)

Comment: I know! we can have as much data based on our memory requirement. But I right now in my project I cant have 4TB of RAM(cost is high). so of course I have to use disk storage. My question was, will it still be a good decision to use redis, even if I am not storing all the data in memory?

Comment: @AD7six even if the dataset doesn't fit in a single server, you can still use Redis & shard the dataset.

Comment: @ItamarHaber that doesn't sound applicable here. Sharding is one way to dividing the data (another alternative is partitioning) so that it can be split across multiple machines - it would still be necessary to have, collectively, enough ram to fit *all* the data in memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Redis is an **in-memory** database, which means you'll need at least 4-5TB of RAM to store your dataset. While this isn't impossible (e.g. see http://www.xdata.me/?p=353 for an 18TB Redis cluster), it is certainly not cheap. On the other hand, nothing beats RAM in terms of performance so if you use Redis for the job you'll probably be getting the best possible performance.

I think a better way to evaluate Redis for this project (or any other database for that matter) is to start with understanding what the data is and what you want to do with it. There are many data management solutions out there, each with its own merits, so understanding the context is crucial before settling on a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Redis might not be  a great option for all the above mentioned reasons , however you an use Cassandra for your kinds of requirement.